# What is missing from this AJAX call code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I apologize for not providing the full code for context, I am VERY new to this. Here is the code for the signup.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    
    $missingUsername='<p><strong>Please enter a username</strong></p>';
    $missingEmail='<p><strong>Please enter your email address</strong></p>';
    $InvalidEmail='<p><strong>Please enter a valid email address</strong></p>';
    $missingPassword='<p><strong>Please enter a password</strong></p>';
    $InvalidPassword='<p><strong>Your password should be at least 6 characters long and include one capital letter and one number</strong></p>';
    $differentPassword='<p><strong>Passwords don\'t match</strong></p>';
    $missingPassword2='<p><strong>Please confirm your password</strong></p>';
    
    if(empty($_POST["username"])){
        $errors .= $missingUsername;
    }else{
        $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST["email"])){
        $errors .= $missingEmail;
    }else{
        $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
           $errors .= $InvalidEmail; 
        }
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST["password"])){
        $errors .= $missingPassword;
    }elseif(!(strlen($_POST["password"])>6 and preg_match('/[A-Z]/',$_POST["password"]) and preg_match('/[0-9]/',$_POST["password"]))){
        $errors .= $InvalidPassword;
    }else{
        $password = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if(empty($_POST["password2"])){
            $errors .= $missingPassword2;
        }else{
            $password2 = filter_var($_POST["password2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if($password !== $password2){
                $errors .= $differentPassword;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if($errors){
        $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors .'</div>'
            echo $resultMessage;
    }
    
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);
    
    $password = hash('sha256', $password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';
        exit;
    }
    $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($results){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">That username is already registered. Do you want to log in?</div>';
        exit;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';
        exit;
    }
    $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($results){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">That email is already registered. Do you want to log in?</div>';
        exit;
    }
    
    $activationKey = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
       
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users ('username', 'email', 'password', 'activation') VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$activationKey')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">There was an error inserting the user details in the database!</div>';
        exit;
    }
    
    $message = "Please click on this link to activate your account:\n\n";
    $message .= "http://studenttest.host20.uk/activate.php?email=" . urlencode($email) . "&key=$activationKey";
    if(mail($email, 'Confirm your Registration', $message, 'From:'.'msyed0230@gmail.com')){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you for registration! Confirmation email has been sent to $email. Please click on the activation link to activate your account.</div>";
    }
?>
```

Here again is the JS code block I'm working with within a broad goal of making a proper sign-up form:

```
$("#signupform").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(datatopost);
    $.ajax({
        url: "signup.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datatopost,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                $("#signupmessage").html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#signupmessage").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax call. Please try again later.</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason, I keep getting the AJAX error instead of the typical error messages I set up for username entry, password entry, etc. It is linked to the correct files (put in the script tag in my main index.php file) and with everything else.

What could be going on?

Comment: Without knowing the handling within `signup.php`, it's hard to know. Could be a syntax error in the handling, using `die()`, or other matters. You may be able to see if the browser's network tab is showing anything related to XHR in the response, or you could add some `error_log` calls at various points in the signup file and check the server log for those outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an error in your signup.php page so it would be better if you put the whole code so as to find the issue and to fix it.

I've made a little example with almost the same code as yours and it works fine :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >


<div id="signupmessage"></div>

<form id="signupform" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name" /><br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter your last name" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#signupform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(datatopost);
        $.ajax({
            url: "signup.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: datatopost,
            success: function(data){
                    $("#signupmessage").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                $("#signupmessage").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

--------- signup.php -----------

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])){
        
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

        
        echo $firstname."<br />";
        echo $lastname;

    }
     else{
         echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax call. Please try again later.</div>";
    }
    
?>
```